# Calendar doesn't render any events after $scope.splice(0) and $scope.push(event)

Tags: ajax, angularjs, fullcalendar

Hi I have problem with angular ui-calendar(angular wrapper for arshaw's fullcalendar).

In the first state I load the events immediately through a $http call. The calendar renders as expected.

In the second step, I load unapproved or approved events according to result of `showNeschvaleneTerminyFunction()`. After this load however, calendar renders, but does not have any events. I verified that the object on scope has events and is being updated correctly by echoing the object on the screen. However the calendar does not ever show the events.

Could you please help me, how can I properly load and reload events with ajax from php driven storage?

Here is my code

```
$scope.events = [];
$scope.getTermins = function(){
    if($scope.showNeschvaleneTerminy == true){
        $http.get(plutanium.ajaxurl + '?action=terminy_read').success(function (data, status, headers, config) {



            $scope.events.splice(0, $scope.events.length);
            $className = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (data[i].status == 0) {
                    $className = 'b-danger';
                } else {
                    $className = 'b-info';
                }
                $scope.events.push({
                    id: data[i].id,
                    title: data[i].jmeno,
                    start: moment(data[i].date).toDate(),
                    end: moment(data[i].date).add('hours', 1).toDate(),
                    allDay: false,
                    className: ['b-l b-2x ' + $className]
                });

            }



        });
    }else{
        $http.get(plutanium.ajaxurl + '?action=terminy_approved').success(function (data, status, headers, config) {



            $scope.events.splice(0, $scope.events.length);
            $className = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                $scope.events.push({
                    id: data[i].id,
                    title: data[i].jmeno,
                    start: moment(data[i].date).toDate(),
                    end: moment(data[i].date).add('hours', 1).toDate(),
                    allDay: false,
                    className: ['b-l b-2x b-info']
                });

            }


        });
    }

}

$scope.getTermins();
$scope.showNeschvaleneTerminyFunction = function () {
    if ($scope.showNeschvaleneTerminy == false) {
        $scope.showNeschvaleneTerminy = true
    } else {
        $scope.showNeschvaleneTerminy = false
    }
    $scope.getTermins();
}

/* config object */
$scope.uiConfig = {
  calendar1:{
      defaultView: 'agendaDay',
      height: $window.innerHeight-200,
      firstDay: 1,
      firstHour: 7,
      slotMinutes: 60,
      defaultEventMinutes: 120,
      minTime: 7,
      maxTime: 15,
    editable: true,
    header:{
      left: '',
      center: 'title',
      right: ''
    },

      dayClick: $scope.AgendaOnDayClick,
    eventClick: $scope.alertOnEventClick,
    eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
    //eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize,
    //eventMouseover: $scope.alertOnMouseOver,

  },
    calendar2: {


        editable: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'next'
        },
        height: $window.innerHeight - 200,
        firstDay: 1,
        minTime: 7,
        maxTime: 15,
        dayClick: $scope.MonthOnDayClick,
        eventClick: $scope.alertOnEventClick,
        eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
        //eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize,
        //eventMouseover: $scope.alertOnMouseOver,
        dayRender: $scope.setDay

    },
    calendar3: {
        defaultView: 'agendaDay',

        editable: true,
        header: {
            left: '',
            center: 'title',
            right: ''
        },
        height: $window.innerHeight - 200,
        firstDay: 1,
        firstHour: 7,
        slotMinutes: 60,
        defaultEventMinutes: 120,
        minTime: 7,
        maxTime: 15,
        dayClick: $scope.AgendaOnDayClick,
        eventClick: $scope.alertOnEventClick,
        eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
        //eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize,
        //eventMouseover: $scope.alertOnMouseOver,

    }
};

$scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I didn't find any solution to my problem, that's why I disabled ui-calendar wrapper and now I am calling fullcalendar refreshevents function manually after loading events to array. It works now like a charm.

Comment: Came here with hope, left with a tear :(